# how to make rxvt start as fullscreen?

Tags: rxvt

I can't find it within man page.
I am using rxvt-unicode-256color from debian squeeze mirror.
Gnome 3 environment, composite enabled in xorg.conf.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Install wmctrl

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Create the extension directory

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.urxvt/ext/
   ```
3. Create a plugin for Rxvt

   ```
   $ vi ~/.urxvt/ext/fullscreen
   #!perl
   sub on_user_command {
       my ($self, $cmd) = @_;
       if ($cmd eq "fullscreen:switch") {
           my $dummy = `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen` ;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Enable the plugin

   ```
   $ vi ~/.Xdefaults
   ...
   " Fullscreen switch
   URxvt.perl-ext-common:  fullscreen
   URxvt.keysym.F11:       perl:fullscreen:switch
   ```

Now, you can toggle fullscreen with the F11 key.

---

Reference:

- [[SOLVED] rxvt-unicode not switching to fullscreen / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1155345#p1155345)
- [my .Xdefaults](https://github.com/chusiang/tuxENV/blob/master/home/_Xdefaults)

Comment: This doesn't start rxvt as fullscreen. It just adss a hotkey to make it fullscreen, which is also possible using most window managers. I tried a similar approach but with on_start instead of on_user_command, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

to go straight to fullscreen at login i put this at the end of my `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ $TERM == *"rxvt"* ]] && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,fullscreen
```

as per [Chu-Siang Lai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686105/chu-siang-lai)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707805/339874) you need to make sure that `wmctrl` is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple perl plugin that will start urxvt in fullscreen mode (without requiring you to press an additional key):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub on_start {
  my ($self) = @_;
  # This is hacky, but there doesn't seem to be an event after 
  # window creation
  $self->{timer} = urxvt::timer->new->after(0.1)->cb(sub {
      fullscreen $self
    });
  return;
}

sub fullscreen {
  my ($self) = @_;
  my $wid = $self->parent;
  my $err = `wmctrl -i -r $wid -b add,fullscreen`;
  warn "Error maximizing: $err\n" unless $? == 0;
  $self->{timer}->stop;
  delete $self->{timer};
  return;
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the window isn't visible to wmctrl when `on_start` is called, so I had to use a timer to delay the call to wmctrl until the window exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved

> running window settings after invoking urxvt.

```
Shell: zsh
Windowmanager: wmctrl
```

**.zsrch**

```
function urxvtmaxed () {
    # &! is a zsh-specific shortcut to both background and disown the process
    urxvt -e zsh -c "RUN='wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz' zsh" &!
}

function urxvtfull () {
    # &! is a zsh-specific shortcut to both background and disown the process
    urxvt -e zsh -c "RUN='wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,fullscreen' zsh" &!
}

### ======================================================
### Run Commands After zsh invoked

eval "$RUN"

# Example
# RUN='my_prog opt1 opt2' zsh

### Run Commands After zsh invoked END
### ======================================================
```

Now in zsh you can run `urxvtmaxed` or `urxvtfull` to launch urxvt and then resizing the window.

> Note: wmctrl doesn't work properly in a Wayland session as controlling
>   windows is against Wayland's security policy.

```
If $WINDOWID is available

urxvt -e zsh -c "RUN='wmctrl -i -r \$WINDOWID -b add,fullscreen' zsh" &!
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, as far as I know. But, I found a workaround:

Use

```
wmctrl -l
```

to find out what your `rxvt` window is named. Probably, its "rxvt", so

```
wmctrl -r rxvt -b toggle,fullscreen
```

will maximize that window.

You'll have to put this (the second command) in a script, that is read **after** your window manager (e.g., openbox, metacity) is loaded. Possibly, in your `.xinitrc` file.

Comment: Thank you. Now i'm using tiling window manager, i think it makes life easier.

Comment: @Yannbane: They can be, but are they for `rxvt`? I used this for `urxvt` and it worked. If the title does change for `rxvt`, you could write a script that greps the line, and feeds the `wmctrl` function with the correct title.

Comment: Sure, grep would work. And I'm not sure about `rxvt`. It doesn't have consistent titles on my system either, so maybe you could update your answer? I'd gladly remove the -1...

Comment: the current window name is `:ACTIVE:`